# Set apostrophe value to #id in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the piece of code i have.

```
function onMemberSelected(link) {
   $('#contract').val(link.attr('Contract'));
   $('#memberID').val(link.attr('MemberID'));
   $('#firstName').val(link.attr('FirstName'));
   **$('#lastName').val(`link.attr('LastName')`);**
   $('#dob').val(link.attr('DOB'));
   $('#address').val(link.attr('Address'));
}
```

the problem is on the above bolded place. If i try to assign a value, it giving me the #lastname value as **"link.attr('LastName')"** rather than the actual value.

Please help.

Comment: What does the HTML you are trying to retrieve this from look like?

Comment: `is a backtick, not an apostrophe. What exactly are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: If you're trying to use a template literal, that's not the correct syntax. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Please exactly describe what you are trying to achieve with that code.

Comment: you are getting this value "link.attr('LastName')"  because you are assigning this value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The below code worked for me.

$('#lastName').val(link.attr('LastName').replace("'","'"));
$('#lastName').val(link.attr('LastName').replace("'","'"));

Comment: It might have worked but replacing `""` with `""` seems to be a strange solution, not sure how valid it is, you should have posted the html as requested 25 min again in order to get are more specific answer